# AWK script syntax has let me down. Trying to output csv file into many new files by column value grouping

Tags: awk

```
cat file1.txt
Item1,200
Item2,500
Item3,900
Item2,800
Item1,600
```

MY ATTEMPT:

```
awk -F, '{print > $1}' file1.txt
```

MY OUTPUT:

```
awk: Syntax error   Context is:
>>>    ,{print  file1.t    <<<<<<
```

from
http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/awk-10-examples-to-split-file-into.html

```
$ cat file1
Item1,200
Item2,500
Item3,900
Item2,800
Item1,600

$ awk -F, '{print > $1}' file1
```

should output

```
$ cat Item1
Item1,200
Item1,600

$ cat Item3
Item3,900

$ cat Item2
Item2,500
Item2,800
```

I have a working .awk script that returns columns 1 and 3 of the test.csv so yes I know how to do this, but this script returns absolutely nothing, the command line just shutters for a second and back to the blinking $.

Comment: What do mean by "returns"? UNIX commands can produce output, e.g. via print, and they always produce an exit status, e.g. via exit, but they don't "return" anything so - do you mean outputs or exists with a status of or something else? wrt the problem you describe - are you sure you have write permission in the directory you are running in and/or for the files you are trying to create?

Comment: Every possible output statement in your `awk` program (all one of them) is redirected to a file. Why would you expect terminal output in such a case?

Comment: Seems to work. What did you want to see at the command line terminal?

Comment: I could answer that if the line itself would execute, can't get past the error

Comment: So now there's a syntax error you didn't think to bring up before? What OS are you running?

Comment: Aside from your current issue - I just read the tutorial page you reference and whoever wrote it does not know awk very well and so most of their scripts use the wrong approach and some rely on undefined behavior and will fail on some POSIX awks tso don't follow their advice. Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Ed thank you will do.   Am running Windows